# Geo Location code returning undefined

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to run the following Geolocation code but the following code is returning undefined. can anyone guide me please

When I call the function for example

alert(verifylocation());

it returns undefined. I want to use this in form validation

```js
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?=$google_api_key?>&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var geocoder, location1, location2, radius_verified;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
radius_verified = - 1;
var Zone1, Zone1_enabled;
var Zone2, Zone2_enabled;
var Zone3, Zone3_enabled;

window.verifylocation = function() {
 var restaurant_location = '<?= $objRestaurant->rest_address . ", " . $objRestaurant->rest_city . ", " . $objRestaurant->rest_state; ?>';
 var customer_location = $("#customer_address").val() + " , " + $("#customer_city").val() + " , " + $("#customer_state").val();
 
    var radius = '<?= $objRestaurant->delivery_radius ?>';
 
    geocoder.geocode({'address': restaurant_location}, function(results, status) {
  // Here is my Code but before my code run it returns undefined.
    });
};
```

Comment: What variable is undefined?

Comment: when I call the function for example alert(verifylocation())

Comment: You are not returning any value in the function. What do you want to return?

Comment: geocoder.geocode({'address': restaurant_location}, function(results, status) {
  // here is my code
    }); //but it return undefiend before this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>

            <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

            <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

            <p id="demo"></p>

            <script>
            var x = document.getElementById("demo");

            function getLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                } else { 
                    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                }
            }

            function showPosition(position) {
                x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
                "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
            }
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```